# Does Jmeter Still have Coordinated Omission Problem?

Tags: jmeter

I've been using JMeter for performance testing tasks for a few years and recently I came across with the term 'Coordinated Omission' which is simply hiding all the worst sides of the response times.
The lecture which I listened to is from 2015 and I would like to know if Jmeter has fixed it or is there any other way to resolve the issue?

Comment: Couldn't it happen with pretty much any load test till? The way to resolve it is by tuning the number of threads based on your hardware (or going distributed if your hardware can't handle your test own). Just search the web.

Comment: All web performance loading tools relying on multithreading to emulate multiple users is prone to the coordinated omission problem, and as far as i know JMeter's design has not significantly changed since then. There is though at least one tool which avoids this pitfall : Gatling, as it relies on non-blocking io and eventloop instead of multithreading to send requests. See https://www.jug.ch/events/slides/180517_Functional_Load_Testing.pdf for a detailed explanation about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore response times peak by using [Percentile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) measure:

> In this way infrequent peaks are ignored

JMeter provide in reports the [90th Percentile](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html):

> 90% Line (90th Percentile) is the value below which 90% of the samples fall. The remaining samples too at least as long as the value. This is a standard statistical measure.

Comment: Correct. But my problem is something like this
Let's assume we have 10 requests to be sent and each request should be sent with a 1s interval. At the 5th request, the system gets a performance issue and it's response time get increased. Due to this does JMeter have delays sending the 6th request?

Comment: @MudithaPerera I won't call it delays, request will just have bigger response time due to issue

Comment: Yep, but due to that all response time data will get affected right?

Comment: @MudithaPerera it's part of the data, you may want to remove, for example using plugin https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/

Comment: Yes, we can use filters to analyze the data. What I'm worried about is does Jmeter give us the exact latencies. I mean is it giving us the response times or service times? I'm also doing an investigation on this. Will give an update if I find anything.